# Finding shared volume of two overlapping cuboids

Tags: algorithm

What is the most efficient way to find the shared space occupied by two overlapping cube objects?

I'm not necessarily looking for source code, just the general idea on how it should be solved.

To simplify, the algorithm doesn't have to take into account rotated cubes.

Answer (score 12):

The overlap of two non-rotated cubes is still a 'box'. If two corner points of box A are (x,y,z) and (x',y',z') (x'>x,y'>y,z'>z) and two corner points of box B are (a,b,c) and (a',b',c') (a'>a,b'>b,c'>c) then the volume of the overlap is

```
max(min(a',x')-max(a,x),0)
* max(min(b',y')-max(b,y),0)
* max(min(c',z')-max(c,z),0)
```

How the read the formula:

The overlap starts on the X axis at the maximum of the two coordinates x and a and ends at the minimum of a' and x'. If a' < x (i.e. a < a' < x < x') then there's no overlap and what happens is that max(a,x) = x > min(a',x') = a', so the difference becomes negative and the volume is zero (hence the outer max(...,0)) term. The same applies for the other two axes.

Answer (score 4):

If the cubes aren't rotated (axis aligned), the overlap of the dimensions is enough to describe the overlap of the cubes.

Consider the problem in 2 dimensions:

```
      ________
     |    S2  |
 ____|___     |
|    |   |    |
|    |___|____|
| S1     |
|________|
```

The overlapping area is described by a width of S1.xmax - S2.xmin, and a height of S1.ymax - S2.ymin.  To determine the order of subtraction requires a couple of `if` tests.  You may find there's no overlap at all.  To do this for cubes, consider the z dimension in addition to x and y.

Answer (score 3):

Compute the min/max in each dimension of each of your cubes and then test these against each other e.g. in the x direction where the cubes are labeled 1 and 2

```
XminInt;
if ( Xmin1 > Xmax2 )
{
    // no intersection
}
else if ( Xmin1 >= Xmin2 )
{
    // possible cube intersection
    XminInt = Xmin1;
}
else if ( Xmin2 <= Xmax1 )
{
    // possible cube intersection
    XminInt = Xmin2;
}
```

Do something similar for the max and repeat both for y and z. If you hit the no intersection case in any of them then you can exit early. If you don't exit early in any of the six possible early exit clauses then you will have all six defining values for the intersection cube i.e. min/max for each dimension.

The six early returns are pretty much the simplest example there is of a [separating axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_axis_theorem) method. Since your shapes are cubes and are axis-aligned the Cartesian axes are the possible separating axes. Testing is then a simple matter of comparing the min/max values as above.

Note that I have implemented the above method in C++ and confirmed that it works.

Comment: This would work for AABBs. How about the case where one or both cubes are not aligned with the Cartesian axes?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question and this is the best thread that comes up but the best answer does not address the question.  After sometime, I have it solved.  Antti answer calculates the volumne as a scalar rather than defining the overlapping cube points.  Using his definition to define a cube, to get the shared space occupied by two overlapping cube objects, that shared cube is:

let box A be a vector (Ax,Ay,Az) and A' be (Ax',Ay',Az') with (Ax'>Ax,Ay'>Ay,Az'>Az)

let box B be a vector (Bx,By,Bz) and B' be (Bx',By',Bz') with (Bx'>Bx,By'>By,Bz'>Bz)

let box C be our new overlapping cube

then the intersection between the two cubes is:
    C  = Min(A', B');
    C' = Max(A, B);

Note if the boxes touch only at a single point, then C = C'.  If only one dimension is different, touches at a line, and if only 2 dimensions are different touches at a plane.

Comment: This method seems to assume an overlap exists. if given A=(0,0,0), A'=(1,1,1), B=(2,2,2), B`=(3,3,3), then C=(1,1,1), C'=(2,2,2), which is not correct. Perhaps, add a caveat "Assuming two cubes overlap..."